# JavaFX: can you define max width/height for a TextField using CSS?

Tags: css, javafx

I want to specify preferred and max width and height for a TextField. Can I do it in CSS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. The Region class in JavaFX supports for example the following CSS attributes: -fx-min-width, -fx-pref-width, -fx-max-width
You can find a complete CSS overview for JavaFX here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: I know about that css ref. My question is about textfield, so how do you use it with region?

Comment: The Textfield extends the region and therefore all CSS properties that are defined for the Region class can be used for a textfield.